# Delete value of a second column if the value of first column is matched

Tags: python

I'm trying to delete the value of a second column if the value of first column is matched, that is if any value in the first column has "Brown" in it. Well, my python code was not good enough to do the job.

My data fileX:

```
Brown_256   good
Sure_278    uncertain
Brown_278   uncertain
Gorino_289  good
Tempar_290  good
```

Expected output:fileY:

```
Brown_256   
Sure_278    uncertain
Brown_278   
Gorino_289  good
Tempar_290  good
```

My attempt:

```
infile=open("fileX.txt", "r")
outfile=open("fileY.txt", "w")
for item in infile:
    item=str(item).split("\t")
    #item=item.strip()
    #print item[1]
    if item[0].startswith("Brown_"):
        print item[1]
        item=item.replace("item[1]","") 
        outfile.write(item+"\t")
```

Can someone let me know why my code did not work as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might write your code like so:

```
for line in infile:
    if line.startswith('Brown'):
        left, sep, right=line.partition('\t')
        outstr=''.join([left, sep])+'\n'
    else:
        outstr=line 
    outfile.write(outstr)
```

(not tested...)

Comment: This does have a trailing `\t` in the case of a single column. This is usually considered an error

Answer (score 0):

Lists don't have method `replace` and you cannot use strings (`"item[1]"`) as actual values (`item[1]`).

Change `item=item.replace("item[1]","")` to `item[1]=""`.